# Displaying an image from string in django template

Tags: django, image, django-templates

To give you an idea of my starting point:

- I have a set of forms with a label and checkbox.
- Some of my labels are supposed to display pictures, but not all.
- The pictures when they should be displayed are never at the same place with regards to the label text (ie sometimes the picture should be displayed in the middle of the label, sometimes at the beginning, end...).

So the only way I could think of to address this problem was to have in my label at some place, something like

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/sources/1/2.jpg" height=300px/>
```

within the text.

The problem is that it is considered as a string and not as an html tag.

Would you have any idea of to address this issue? I'm currently run out of ideas.

Thank you very much.
Soso :)

Comment: are you rending html tags with django views?

Comment: Yes. I'm passing all my form which as several fields each containing a `forms.MultipleChoiceField` and the label of some of them has the above `<img...` in it at some place.

Comment: Would you mind to show your `views.py` file and the actual value of an `img` by right-click and inspecting it?

Comment: @nik_m I manage to make it work as per the below answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. The only thing I needed was to wrap my label containing my former `<img>` tag with:

```
mark_safe
```

imported using

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
```

Thanks!